# python chatterbot call function instead of providing a text response back

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

I am trying to create a chatbot in python that depending on the user questions and confirmations, I execute a specific python function, adding data to a database, for example. From what I have seen, chatterbot is able to respond text answers back depending on the question, but I couldn´t find anything on how I can trigger functions based on answers. Do you know how I could accomplish that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is train chatterbot to give a certain response to what you want to trigger. Then check what response is, and if it is the trigger, run a function.

Here is an example. Let's say you want to run function `blablabla()` when the user says `bla`.

```py
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

bot = ChatBot('IsaacBot')

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")

trainer = ListTrainer(bot)

trainer.train([
    'blablabla',
    'runblablabla'
])

def blablabla():
    print("blablabla")

while True:
    query = input(">>> ")
    if str(bot.get_response(query)) == "runblablabla":
        blablabla()
    else:
        print(bot.get_response(query))
```

If you want to only run `blablabla` if the user exactly says `blablabla` then you can just check if the query is `blablabla`. But using the training method will also run `blablabla` if the user says something similar.

**NOTE:** Remember to have other training data, like in the example I used the corpus training data, because if you don't it will just answer `runblablabla` to everything you say, always running the function.